# Posting run action using Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to use Graph API from Facebook iOS SDK.

So far I managed to post simple status update using:

```
[connection addRequest:[FBRequest requestForPostStatusUpdate:@"Test"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) [self.appDelegate showUnknownCommunicationError];
     }];
[connection start];
```

Next I tried to post run action using [provided sample:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.runs/)

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
action[@"course"] = @"http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614";

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/fitness.runs"
                                   graphObject:action
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 // handle the result
                             }];
```

This doesn't throw any error, but also nothing appears on my wall. I thought it's because, the app id from this sample doesn't match mine, so I tried to build course myself like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];

action[@"fb:app_id"] = FB_APP_ID;
action[@"og:type"] = @"fitness.course";
action[@"og:title"] = @"Sample Course";
action[@"og:image"] = @"https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png";
action[@"og:description"] = @"Test description";
action[@"og:url"] = @"https://mysite.pl/";
```

This throws error and says, that my object lack the course property. I'm confused now...

The action Run for my app is not revieved yet, but I guess it's not the point since I'm testing it with my developer account.

**EDIT. I got tons of logs from Facebook logger:**

```
FBSDKLog: Request <#1111>:
  URL:  https://graph.facebook.com
  Method:   POST
  UserAgent:    FBiOSSDK.3.10.0
  MIME: multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
  Body (w/o attachments):   
    batch_app_id:   1409052495999988
    batch:  [{"method":"POST","relative_url":"me\/fitness.runs?sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20131015&format=json&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED","body":"course=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2F136756249803614"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"method\/auth.extendSSOAccessToken?sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20131015&format=json&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED"}]

2013-12-23 09:28:53.756 RunGuru[1559:60b] FBSDKLog: Response <#1111>
Duration: 1551 msec
Size: 1672 kB
Response Body:
(
        {
        body =         {
            id = 10201708817820717;
        };
        code = 200;
        headers =         (
                        {
                name = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
                value = "*";
            },
                        {
                name = "Cache-Control";
                value = "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            },
                        {
                name = Connection;
                value = close;
            },
                        {
                name = "Content-Type";
                value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
            },
                        {
                name = Expires;
                value = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
            },
                        {
                name = Pragma;
                value = "no-cache";
            },
                        {
                name = "x-fb-loadmon";
                value = "0,67.29,30";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        body =         {
            "error_code" = 3;
            "error_msg" = "Unknown method";
            "request_args" =             (
                                {
                    key = sdk;
                    value = ios;
                },
                                {
                    key = "migration_bundle";
                    value = "fbsdk:20131015";
                },
                                {
                    key = format;
                    value = json;
                },
                                {
                    key = "access_token";
                    value = ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED;
                },
                                {
                    key = "_fb_url";
                    value = "method/auth.extendSSOAccessToken";
                },
                                {
                    key = "_fb_profilable_request_id";
                    value = 1747586569;
                },
                                {
                    key = method;
                    value = "auth_extendssoaccesstoken";
                },
                                {
                    key = "_fb_batch_child_request";
                    value = 1;
                },
                                {
                    key = "_fb_batch_expires";
                    value = 1387787339;
                },
                                {
                    key = "_fb_batch_sig";
                    value = AfiDnh1EPSHTbQKV;
                }
            );
        };
        code = 200;
        headers =         (
                        {
                name = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
                value = "*";
            },
                        {
                name = "Cache-Control";
                value = "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            },
                        {
                name = Connection;
                value = close;
            },
                        {
                name = "Content-Type";
                value = "application/json";
            },
                        {
                name = Expires;
                value = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
            },
                        {
                name = Pragma;
                value = "no-cache";
            },
                        {
                name = "x-fb-loadmon";
                value = "0,67.29,30";
            }
        );
    }
)

2013-12-23 09:29:48.899 RunGuru[1559:60b] FBSDKLog: Request <#1115>:
  URL:  https://graph.facebook.com/1409052495999988?fields=supports_attribution,supports_implicit_sdk_logging,suppress_native_ios_gdp,name&format=json&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20131015&sdk=ios
  Method:   GET
  UserAgent:    FBiOSSDK.3.10.0
  MIME: multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f

2013-12-23 09:29:49.183 RunGuru[1559:60b] FBSDKLog: Response <#1115>
Duration: 283 msec
Size: 138 kB
Response Body:
(
        {
        body =         {
            id = 1409052495999988;
            name = RunGuru;
            "supports_attribution" = 1;
            "supports_implicit_sdk_logging" = 1;
            "suppress_native_ios_gdp" = 1;
        };
        code = 200;
    }
)

2013-12-23 09:29:49.207 RunGuru[1559:60b] FBSDKLog: Request <#1119>:
  URL:  https://graph.facebook.com/1409052495999988/activities?advertiser_tracking_enabled=1&url_schemes=%5B%22fb1409052495999988%22%5D&bundle_version=0.2&bundle_short_version=0.2&event=CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20131015&sdk=ios&application_tracking_enabled=1&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED&bundle_id=pl.runguru.ios.app&advertiser_id=A3D3020D-C158-4485-A2E3-E886FC4FA54D&format=json
  Method:   POST
  UserAgent:    FBiOSSDK.3.10.0
  MIME: multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
  Body Size:    0 kB
  Attachments:  
    advertiser_tracking_enabled:    1
    url_schemes:    ["fb1409052495999988"]
    bundle_version: 0.2
    bundle_short_version:   0.2
    event:  CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS
    migration_bundle:   fbsdk:20131015
    sdk:    ios
    application_tracking_enabled:   1
    access_token:   ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED
    bundle_id:  pl.runguru.ios.app
    advertiser_id:  A3D3020D-C158-4485-A2E3-E886FC4FA54D
    format: json
    custom_events_file: <Data - 0 kB>

2013-12-23 09:29:49.421 RunGuru[1559:60b] FBSDKLog: Response <#1119>
Duration: 213 msec
Size: 4 kB
Response Body:
(
        {
        body =         {
            "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = true;
        };
        code = 200;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code working fine, Strange thing is that the activity doesn't appear on there timeline feed for some reason. If you take a look at your activity log for your app by first going on your profile --> activity log button near cover pic, you see it been created.

Best method to confirm this works is to console out all facebook events using the following code:

```
[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, nil]];
```

Next time you run your code you will see the actually HTTP request that been sent and also the response back from facebook which should contain the new id of the graph object.

Comment: It gives me a lot of feedback. Unfortunatelly none of it makes any sense to me :/

Comment: Could you share the output?

Comment: Can't find this activity log you are talking about. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Try this direct like: www.facebook.com/"USERNAME"/allactivity

Comment: Oh well, it's there... wonder whi sin't it on the timeline. On this screen I can switch from allowed on timeline to shown on timeline... but it should be displayed on the timeline by default, shouldnt it?

Comment: open graph activities initially show up only under the recent activities section. Once the app has generated considerable traffic and met facebook requirement , it will start to show up on timelines. here a link with details: [Explicit Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing)

Comment: fb:explicit_sharing is definitely the key to making this work. Without that permission you can only post to the all activity or /user/fitness tab.